# Is there a way to see all my app's plugin dependencies?

Tags: plugins, grails, dependencies

My Grails application uses a bunch of plugins.  Those plugins use other plugins.

Now I'm considering moving to MongoDB and removing Hibernate.  I need to know what plugins, if any, require Hibernate.

Is there any way to get a dump, printout or other visualization of what plugins each of my plugins require?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still haven't found a authoritative way to find a Grails plugin's dependencies.  However, I've been able to spelunk through my installed plugins' code to find the answers.

Your IDE should list the plugins.  In your IDE, go to each one, like:
$pluginDir/tomcat-1.3.7/

Dependencies might be declared in any of these files:

- **[PluginName]GrailsPlugin** <-- has a `dependsOn` clause that lists plugins.
- **application.properties** <-- lists plugins this plugin depends on.  Newer plugins seem to use this file the most.
- **dependencies.groovy** <-- seems to just declare library dependencies (like apache commons).  Haven't seen a plugin dependency declared here yet.

FWIW, both the Spring Security and Quartz plugins depend directly on Hibernate.

Answer (score 10):

You should also try to run `grails dependency-report` from the command line.  It should list all dependencies for your project and plugins in a HTML report.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about dependency-report.  It's cool and will definitely stay in my toolchest!  Unfortunately, it doesn't show plugin dependencies... unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

The command line  `grails list-plugin` maybe what you need. Navigate to your project folder and executing this command will give you the list of all installed plugins in your project. The details of the command can be found [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/list-plugins.html).

Comment: @Dean: another way, in Windows(i'm not sure about Linux), you can navigate to home folder of current user("John", for example), and navigate to 'John\.grails\1.3.6\projects\YOUR_PROJECT\plugins'

Comment: @hoang-long:  That gives me a list of all the installed plugins, but not what plugins those plugins require.   I need to know which of those plugins require hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

grails list-plugins  : lists all the plugins in grails central repository

---

grails list-plugins -installed  : lists all plugins currently used in a particular application

---

grails plugin-info  : gives plugin info along with dependencies

---

**Example :**
$ grails plugin-info spring-security-core